# Make constant conditional in php using static method

Tags: php, constants

I'm trying to make IntegratedApp class constant use value from the config file and then use the constant in MakeConnectionController. But the constant PORTAL_BASE_URL_STAG, inside the IntegratedApp class, when assigning a static method to it, an **underline error (error message: Constant expression contains invalid operations)** appeared on the constant. Is there a way to assign variables to the constant class without using the static method?

Code Example:

config file :

```
[test]
stagingApiUrl = 'https://api-test-first.com/';
```

IntegratedApp.php file :

```
namespace Project\Constants;

class IntegratedApp
{

    const PORTAL_BASE_URL_STAG = self::getUrl();

    public static function getUrl() {
        $base_url = $this->config->test->stagingApiUrl ? $this->config->test->stagingApiUrl : 'https://api-test-second.com/';

        return (string)$base_url;
    }

}
```

MakeConnectionController.php file:

```
use Project\Constants\IntegratedApp;


class MakeConnectionController extends BaseController
{
    $baseUrl = IntegratedApp::PORTAL_BASE_URL_STAG;
}
```

Comment: Constants are defined at compile time and as such must be constant expressions. Constants cannot be "conditional" or "dynamic" by definition. Also you cannot reference `$this` in a static context either as `$this` is the instance context. What value does having the constant or static there bring you that just using an ordinary instance method does not?

Comment: Hi @Sammitch, apart from the '$this' issue. Why I need to make a constant dynamic because currently, I'm working with old code and the constant has been used by 100+ functions. My objective now is to make a constant dynamic to avoid changing all the previous code using that constant. If you have another alternative that I can use, it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: "dynamic constant" is not a thing that is going to exist as each word negates the other.

Comment: yep, true @Sammitch, but the scenario provided above gives me little option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this workaround ( use define() ):

```
<?php
namespace Project\Constants;

define('PORTAL_BASE_URL_STAG',IntegratedApp::getUrl());

class IntegratedApp
{

    const PORTAL_BASE_URL_STAG = PORTAL_BASE_URL_STAG;

    public static function getUrl() {

        return (string)"Foo";
    }

}


print IntegratedApp::PORTAL_BASE_URL_STAG;//Foo
```

- define() a constant outside of the class in the same file
- use the static method for getting the value
- then use the created constant to set the class constant

Hopfully, you have not so mutch magic going on.
And you should fix the `$this` usage, because in static methods you dont have an access to `$this`.

Don't ask why this works :-) It works. Seems like there is a kind of late class constant binding going on here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, and for *$this* usage issue I use *parse_ini_file* to read the information I want from the config file. You really help me mitigate the issue I was having.